# Migrating node code base to TypeScript: global scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to migrate large node codebase to TypeScript. To make things easier, I just want to start by renaming .js files to .ts files, fix any semantic issues, without much refactoring, and then gradually improve the code base.

Let's consider the following example:

logger.js:

```
exports = function(string) {
    console.log(string);
}
```

moduleA.js:

```
var logger = require('./logger')    
exports.someAction = function() {
    logger.log('i'm in module a')
}
```

moduleB.js:

```
//var logger = require('./logger')    
exports.someOtherAction = function() {
    logger.log('i'm in module B')
}
```

moduleC.js:

```
var moduleA = require('./moduleA');  
var moduleB = require('./moduleB');  
exports.run = function(string) {
    moduleA.someAction();
    moduleB.someOtherAction(); //exception here - logger not defined
}
```

So if i execute moduleB.someOtherAction() i'll get an exception, because logger is not defined in scope in moduleB.js.

But typescript compiles just fine, because logger is declared in moduleA, and this is because (if i understand correctly) typescript treats all of those files as a single compilation unit.

So is there anyway to avoid this without much refactoring?

**Update**

I've created a sample project [which can be found here](https://github.com/gytisgreitai/ts-demo)
If i run typescript compiler, i get no errors, though logger is commented out in moduleB.ts:

```
g@w (master) ~/projects/ts-demo: gulp generate
[10:39:46] Using gulpfile ~/projects/ts-demo/gulpfile.js
[10:39:46] Starting 'generate'...
[10:39:46] Starting 'clean'...
[10:39:46] Finished 'clean' after 11 ms
[10:39:46] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[10:39:47] Finished '<anonymous>' after 1.4 s
[10:39:47] Finished 'generate' after 1.41 s
g@w (master) ~/projects/ts-demo:
```

**Update 2**

Ok, so this is expected behaviour as stated in [TypeScript deep dive book](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/project/modules.md):

> If you now create a new file bar.ts in the same project, you will be allowed by the TypeScript type system to use the variable foo from foo.ts as if it was available globally

Comment: That's incorrect. Typescript treats each file as an individual unit. (except for declaration files). What is the value/type of `logger` in modelB? You should be able to see it in your IDE by hovering on it.

Comment: it says var logger: any. I've created a demo project, see updated question

Comment: The "update 2" statement is true, but not when targeting node. It will work the same way node does, that is; each file is its own "module", only available in another file if imported correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer, you have managed to create yourself an interesting case. But the root of it is that every file is its own closed scope when compiling for commonjs, therefore you always need to import a file into another file where you need access to it.

Comment: You're missing the "module" config var, so Typescript treats your whole project as one file. Check my answer.

Comment: This is actually documented by the way (but I can't remember where). It says that when don't specify a "module" config Typescript expects you to load all files in your browser. Nodejs projects should always use "commonjs".

Answer (score 0):

Louy is right. Every file (when compiling for node with CommonJS) is created like its own module. Just like the normal case in node.

So to get this to work you could do something like this:

*logger.ts*

```
export default (str: string) => console.log(str);
```

*moduleA.ts*

```
import logger from './logger';

export var someAction = () => {
     logger("i'm in module a");
}
```

*moduleB.ts*

```
import logger from './logger';

export var someOtherAction = () => {
    logger("i'm in module B");
}
```

*moduleC.ts*

```
import { someAction } from './moduleA';  
import { someOtherAction } from './moduleB';

someAction();
someOtherAction();
```

I also used a *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "files": [
        "logger.ts",
        "moduleA.ts",
        "moduleB.ts",
        "moduleC.ts"
    ]
}
```

Compiling this (just type *tsc* in the folder containing the tsconfig.json) results in one .js file per .ts file. It should compile and run just fine. The main thing you need to take from this is that each file is its own self contained module when compiling for node/CommonJS.

EDIT Due to edits in question:

Ok after looking at your code again there is a couple of reasons that this compiles but fail to run properly:

1. If you send a group of files to the compiler all references in all of those files, and all of the variables in the global scope will be available in all .ts files sent to the compiler. This is confusing and sometimes regrettable, but at the moment it is how things work. This in your case results in that the `require` function defined in the global scope in node.d.ts is available in all .ts files, not only in *moduleC.ts*; if the reference is removed from *moduleC.ts* you will get an error in logger.ts because the require function is not defined for example. It also results in `var logger = ..` defined in *logger.ts* will be seen as available in the other .ts files. Typescript assumes that it will be available at run time.. not ideal when compiling for node, but not a problem when you are writing actual typescript not trying to compile pure javascript. In fact, because it is pure javascript the compiler does not recognise it as a node module, and treats it as a generic javascript file.
2. When compiling with commonjs each file is compiled on its own by the typescript compiler. If any *references* or *imports* are found those will be followed and used to type and verify the code of course, but the compilation is still done on a per file basis (`var something = require('./whatever');` is not an import, it is interpreted by the compiler as a variable being assigned by a function taking a string as an argument.)

So thats why it compiles, lets go on to why its not working then.

Each file outputted by the compiler in commonjs mode is its own "node-module". If you want to have access to one module from within another in node (this has nothing to do with typescript really, it is just how node works) you will need to require that file. in *moduleB.ts* (and in moduleB.js for that matter) there is no indication to node to say what logger is. So you simply need to require logger.

In the example you are referring to in your second update of the question commonjs is not being used, and further more it is in connection with typescripts internal modules - not node modules which is a completely different thing.

So the simple answer is, that if you want to use one file from within a another in node you have to require it. Simply uncommenting the commented reference in *moduleB.ts* should get everything up and running.

In the current state of your code the typescript compiler is not helping you much, because it can't really. The code is close to pure javascript, to get decent help from the compiler you will need to start converting it to typescript. The first step might be to replace `var asdf = require("")` with `import asdf = require("");`, this will make it possible for the compiler to check the references and help you a lot in return.

I realise this is a wordy answer, but you managed to create yourself a confusing and difficult to explain behaviour.

Comment: Yes, well this involves complete rewrite of modules, which as I said, i would like to avoid, cause i have hundreds of them, and migration would take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

There's something called internal/external modules in typescript.

Internal modules can declare stuff that can be referenced everywhere in the project. Think about typings/lib files, you should be able to reference things like `Error` and `String` everywhere in your project.

External modules on the other hand have to be imported to be referenced. This is what you want to do.

The difference between internal and external modules is that external ones use `import` and `export`. 
Internal ones use `declare module/namespace/var`.

Just add `"compilerOptions": {"module": "commonjs"}` to your `tsconfig.json` file to enable external modules.

Comment: And that makes no difference. Still compiles fine :)

Comment: well, these files are still treated as internal modules because they have no import/export statements. "exports.someAction" doesn't work. You need to use "export function someAction()". Add any import/export statement to that file and the issue will appear.

Comment: When you say "var something" in an internal module, it gets recognised as a global variable. I found this really confusing at first —to understand the difference between internal and external modules— but in the end this is how things are.

Comment: and btw, never use "var". replace everything with "let" and change some to "const".

Comment: Everything is fine, but we're now starting to talk about how typescript works, and missing the main point here - i have hundreds of files like these, and i don't have the luxury to migrate them all to typescript export syntax, or suddenly change everything to let or const. Luckily everything is covered with tests, so i'll have to live with that.

Comment: I understand you. just do a global search for "var " and replace it with "let ". same thing for "exports". it's the only solution I know.

Comment: I think a regex search/replace for `var ... = require(` to `import ... = require` wouldn't be hard to do.

Comment: the latter should be enough btw. skip the "let" part.